# Why can't this simple oemof-model be optimized?

Tags: python, optimization, solver

I want to build a model for the distribution of electrical energy. I use the Python package oemof (https://github.com/oemof/oemof)
I would like to start with a very simple model. It consists only of a source (`SRC, fixed`), a sink (`SNK, fixed`) and a storage (`STO, half filled`). All three elements are connected to the same bus (`BUS`).
I would expect if `SRC>SNK` the `STO` is charged and if `SRC<SNK` the `STO` is discharged.
In both cases, nothing happens to `STO` and I get the following error message:

> `ERROR:root:Optimization failed with status ok and terminal condition infeasible`

If `SRC=SNK` no errors are shown.

My code looks like:

```
import oemof.solph as solph
from oemof.outputlib import processing

es = solph.EnergySystem()    
BUS = solph.Bus(label='BUS')

SRC = solph.Source(label='SRC',
                      outputs={BUS: solph.Flow(actual_value=0.8,
                                                  nominal_value=100,
                                                  fixed=True)})
STO = solph.components.GenericStorage(label='STO',
                                         nominal_capacity=100000,
                                         initial_capacity=0.5,
                                         inputs={BUS: solph.Flow()},
                                         outputs={BUS: solph.Flow()})
SNK = solph.Sink(label='SNK',
                    inputs={BUS: solph.Flow(fixed=True,
                                               actual_value=0.5,
                                               nominal_value=100)})

es.add(BUS, SRC, STO, SNK)
om = solph.Model(es)
om.solve(solver='cbc', solve_kwargs={'tee': True})
print(processing.results(om))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Given that this is about a programming issue, the question would benefit from having more context and possibly better tags, so people here have a better idea. As it is, it seems the issue is more about electrical stuff and less about programming, hence it will more likely remain answerless forever here.

Comment: thank you, @Frederik.L. my explanation wasn't really clear!
meanwhile i found an answer: the `initial_capacity`of the `STO`is also the final capacity. considering only one time step the actual capacity can't change.